# Capture starting the end of a non capturing group

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a sentence that comes after a capturing group. At this moment I got this regex:
`(?!.*foo).*`

So, when I test it on the follow string:

foofoofooCopyStartingHere

The engine returns:

ooCopyStartingHere

How can I ignore the "oo" part?

ps: The starting copy tag is not under my control and it may change the length (but maintain a pattern).

Testers tried:

http://regex101.com/r/jU2eY4

http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=(%3F!.*foo).*&input=foofoofoo.e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<=foo)(?!foo)(.+)`

The idea is that you look-behind for a `foo`, then check that there is no `foo` following it, and then capture anything following it.

You don't mention anything about stopping condition, so this will go on for the rest of the line, is this as intended?

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. And, yes, it was intended to get the rest of the line after.

Comment: I just changed the pattern to `(?<=foo)(?!.*foo)(.+)` as the string before the last mark has another marks that doesn't matter for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this :

```
(?<=foo|^)(?>[^f]+|f(?!oo))+
```

The pattern start to check if there is a "foo" before or the start of the string. Then `(?>[^f]+|f(?!oo))+` allows all that is not "foo" (all character that is not "f" or "f" not followed by "oo")